# Approximating Continuous Function and Modulus of Continuity

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f : [0,1]^n \rightarrow [0,1]$ is a continuous function that obeys a modulus of continuity $\Gamma$. For any $\epsilon > 0$, is there a rational coefficient polynomial $p$ which also obeys the modulus of continuity $\Gamma$ and the distance in the sup norm between $p$ and $f$ is less than $\epsilon$, i.e. $\sup_{x \in [0,1]^n}|f(x) - p(x)| < \epsilon$?

---

A function $f$ obeys a modulus of continuity $\Gamma$ if and only if $d(f(x),f(y)) < \Gamma(d(x,y))$ for all $x,y \in [0,1]^n$.

Comment: Is $\Gamma$ a constant?

Comment: @zhw. $\Gamma : (\mathbb{R}^{\geq 0}) \rightarrow (\mathbb{R}^{\geq 0})$ which is continuous, non-decreasing, and $\Gamma(0) = 0$. I believe these are all the properties that a modulus of continuity needs to satisfy.